# Does Coverage plugins need that unit tests run beforehand

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage

I couldnt find this info anywhere. In order to get code coverage calculated using a plugin (like Jococo, Cobertura..etc) Do I need to run all the unit tests before? These look like relevant tasks, But still I think Code coverage should not be dependent on running unit tests before hand,  unless coverage plugin really relies on the Junit

Comment: No you don't have to run all your tests. The coverage does it itself.

Comment: @Kabulan0lak tnx you have any reference for this?

Comment: Personally, I use Emma coverage which works perfectly with my tests. See http://emma.sourceforge.net/docs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not *need* to run tests beforehand. The coverage tool instruments the code (if required), runs the tests (or your `main`) and then reports the stats back to you.

Having said that, if your code relies of fancy reflection/bytecode manipulation, it may be a good idea to run tests beforehand, just to make sure that failures reported during the coverage scan the the instrumentation's fault and not "real" test failures.